# React Native - Set foreground color of View

Tags: react-native

I want to set `foreground color` of `View` so that I can achieve something like this -

[image: My imag]

Example:

```
<View style={{ foregroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' }}>
    //...
</View>
```

Comment: The image is not showing.

Comment: Oh sorry, edited it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `backgroundColor`?

```js
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' }}>
    // Your red button here
</View>
```

This would produce the desired result.